# Flink error on using RichAggregateFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use an implementation of the abstract [RichAggregateFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RichAggregateFunction.html) in Flink.  I want it to be "rich" because I need to store some state as part of the aggregator, and I can do this since I have access to the runtime context.  My code is something like below:

```
stream.keyBy(...)
   .window(GlobalWindows.create())
   .trigger(...)
   .aggregate(new MyRichAggregateFunction());
```

However, I get an UnsupportedOperationException saying

> This aggregation function cannot be a RichFunction.

I'm clearly not using RichAggregateFunction correctly.  Is there any example of how to properly use it?  Or should I be using a ProcessFunction for this sort of operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a mistake on your side.

Flink doesn't support functions that extend `RichAggregateFunction` in a group window.

Comment: Thanks Fabian.   Can you provide some guidance on what sort of use cases RichAggregateFunction would be applicable?

Comment: Right now `AggregateFunction` can only be used in group windows, but this will probably change in future versions.

Comment: Is there any other option to implement an aggregation with a stateful variable over a window like in RichFunctions?

Comment: No, it's still not supported. I'm also not sure if it ever will be supported because there are some conceptual issues with it.